# How to enqueue data from a python function into a TensorFlow queue

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a python function that automatically generates a a (data,label) pair when I call it. I don't know how to attach this function to a TensorFlow FIFOQueue, so that the queue is filled with the data generated from my function. The code I have so far is:

```
myq = tf.FIFOQueue(5000, [tf.float32, tf.float32], [[4],[1]])
enqueue_op = myq.enqueue(read_data()) # read_data() returns two numpy arrays of shape [4] and [1]
qr = tf.train.QueueRunner(myq, [enqueue_op]*2)
...
threads = qr.create_threads(sess=sess,coord=coord, start=True)
```

However, this only calls the function read_data() once and keeps pushing the same value into the queue. How do I correctly hook up my function to the enqueue method, so that I can populate the queue with data from my function (preferably using multiple threads in the background). Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that `read_data` is your own code, not TF operations. You need a placeholder for the `enqueue_op`, then feed the data using `feed_dict`.

```
# Graph setup
x_enqueue = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(4))
y_enqueue = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(1))
enqueue_op = myq.enqueue([x_enqueue, y_enqueue])

...

# Enqueue loop:
x_read, y_read = read_data()
sess.run(enqueue_op, feed_dict={x_enqueue: x_read, y_enqueue: y_read})
```

Comment: Ah. So this setup is not really compatible with the tf.train.QueueRunner and I need to write my own code for threading and looping the enqueue op? (and yes, read_data() does not contain any TF operations)

Comment: Good question! I had the same question when I set up my first queues. I haven't used QueueRunner yet, my understanding from reading the docs is that it would only work if you enqueued your data from the graph, which I infer to mean that it only supports loading data from tensorflow files, or anything that a TF reader can support. If you are generating the data in your own function you'll need to pass it to the graph, and that means placeholders.

Comment: Note, you can still use `tf.train.Coordinator()` to coordinate shutdown and looping operations, just not `QueueRunner()`. Remember to close your queue with `cancel_pending_enqueue_operations=True` to get your enqueue operations to bail out.